# Is there a `--language` flag for cli wallet?

Tags: mnemonic-seed, monero-wallet-cli, language, rpc, creation

There's a `--password` flag and `--generate-new-wallet` flag, which make programmatic generation of a wallet very easy, except for this missing piece. Ideally a command like this would generate a wallet and start the JsonRPC:

```
monero-wallet-cli \
    --generate-new-wallet=foo \
    --password="secret" \
    --language=0 # english
```

but I haven't seen this in the `--help` listing. If this flag doesn't exist, then that would force programmers to supply the `0` to the process via stdin, which is very fragile.

Answer (score 3):

There is none.

This is a good candidate to open a bug on https://github.com/monero-project/bitmonero/issues. It's also a good first task for a new contributor, and if none pick it up, it'll get done by an existing one.